# Removing query string through web.config ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I have a situation where i need to remove query strings from url.

example 1 : https://www.sample.com/**?glCountry=AU&glCurrency=AUD**

example 2 : https://www.sample.com/christmas-gifts**?glCountry=US&glCurrency=USD**

Can i achive this through web.config ? i am using ASP.NET MVC C# hosted in IIS

Comment: I need to remove glCountry=AU&glCurrency=AUD

Comment: You want to replace them with what?

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

Comment: @mjwills I don't want to replace with anything, just need these removing.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/609830/how-to-modify-querystring-using-url-rewriting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule can work well in my test.

```
<rule name="remove querstring" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
         <conditions>
             <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="glCountry=.*" />
             </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

When I check fail request tracing log, it shows that querystring has been removed.
[image]